# Can one use the Sentri car lane when entering the USA from Mexico by bicycle?

Tags: usa, borders, mexico, bicycles, sentri

I have Global Entry. If the answer is specific to the port of entry, then I'm mostly interested in the ports of entry in San Diego.

Comment: Can you, reasonably, safely reach that borderpoint on bicycle on both sides of the border?

Comment: @Willeke yes from Mexican side. Unsure for the US side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the answer for sure, and can't find anything online, however I will make these three observations:

1. Your vehicle must be registered with TTP to use the SENTRI car lanes.  I don't believe you can register a bicycle in SENTRI (needs registration details)
2. The US side of the San Ysidro and Otay Mesa ports-of-entry is freeway, where you cannot ride your bike.
3. You CAN take your bike through the pedestrian border crossing (many do every day) and there is SENTRI/Global Entry access to bypass the long line of pedestrians at both ports-of-entry.